# Question on how Experience Replay solves the traditional instability of online Q-learning (benefits of Experience replay)

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, reinforcement-learning

My question is in regards to how Experience replay solves a traditional instability problem of RL combined with NN. Experience replay solves several instability issues, but the part that I am trying to understand is the following:

**Cause for instability:**
the fact that small updates to Q may significantly change the policy and therefore change the data distributions.

**Solution:**
With experience replay, the behavior distribution is averaged over many of its states, smoothing out learning and avoiding oscillations or divergence in the parameters.

**My interpretation of those cause and solution is now:**

**Interpretation for Cause for instability:**
With learning online (with non-stationary training sample distribution which next training sample is determined by agent's current action), "small" updates to Q-values potentially can abruptly change the ongoing policy (neural networks try to converge toward some good policy). Abrupt change in the ongoing policy also abruptly changes the next time-step's training sample distribution (as in an 'online-setting', now's action determined by now's policy determines next training sample ). And this can potentially lead to "unwanted feedback loops" (which means that the neural network can't converge but diverge/oscillate due to these loops of abrupt changes in policy)

**Interpretation for Solution:**
Experience replay resolves the problem of such potential abrupt changes in ongoing policy(which can lead to unwanted feedback loops -> divergence of NN ), because it averages out policy exploration (behavior distribution) over "many" previous states (mini-batch). Unlike online Q-learning, which policy is determined by one most recent training sample, Experience replay uses multiple training samples (of previous states) as the size of predetermined mini-batch. This enables smoothing out the learning of weights and policy and can avoid abrupt changes in ongoing policy.

Please tell me if I am understanding correctly.